# INVALID_SKILL_RESPONSE for alexa skill

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I just started to build my own web service for alexa skill.

My web service support HTTPS, and the endpoint was hit when I used the alexa simulator for testing, but I got the error 'INVALID_SKILL_RESPONSE'.

This is the simple response from my php code:

```
    return response(
        [
            'version' => '1.0',
            'response' => [
                'outputSpeech' => [
                    'type' => 'PlainText',
                    'text' => 'Hello world',
                ]
            ]
        ],
        200,
        [
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        ]
    );
```

What could cause the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where this `response` function is coming from.
Try something like this:

```
<?php
$responseArray = [
        'version' => '1.0',
        'response' => [
              'outputSpeech' => [
                    'type' => 'PlainText',
                    'text' => 'Hello World'
              ],
              'shouldEndSession' => true
        ]
  ];

header( 'Content-Type: application/json' );
echo json_encode( $responseArray );

?>
```